# makefile sh. command not found // in travis-ci

Tags: linux, makefile, command, sh, travis-ci

This is a part of my makefile

```
OsConf= ./LinuxWindowsScript.sh
```

and this is error log in my travis-ci

```
0.01s$ make lint
./LinuxWindowsScript.sh
make: ./LinuxWindowsScript.sh: Command not found
Makefile:53: recipe for target 'lint' failed
make: *** [lint] Error 127
The command "make lint" exited with 2.
```

How could I resolve it?
What should I do?

Comment: Its a little hard to tell for sure from what you've provided, but first guess would be that your script doesn't have execute permissions. try chmod +x ./LinuxWindowsScript.sh and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Did you forget to `git add` the script?

Comment: Are you trying set a variable?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: Where are your `makefile` and script `LinuxWindowsScript.sh` located? What is your current working directory and how exactly do you run `make`? Show at least the parts of your `makefile` that lead to the execution of the script. Maybe when you run `make` in your CI, the current working directory is different from when you run `make` manually. To check this, add a commands `pwd` and `ls -l` in recipe lines before the script is supposed to run.